# What happens if not all nodes ACKnowledged CAN bus frame?

Tags: can

Let's say we have a CAN bus network of 3 nodes: `nodeA` `nodeB` `nodeC`

`nodeA` broadcasts an important frame that `nodeC` needs but it gets corrupted on the way to `nodeC`(CRC check failed @ `nodeC`) but `nodeB` receives it just fine and sets ACK dominant bit.

Does it mean that `nodeA` is not going to attempt to repeat the frame and `nodeC` missed it completely?

Comment: yes, a single node setting the ack is enough

Comment: read your question ... it has a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a CAN message is acknowledged by any node, this only means that the message was physically transmitted correctly. Not that the intended recipient (`nodeC`) has received the message correctly. `nodeA` won't retransmit the message.

`nodeC`, having detected a CRC error, will increment its REC (receive error counter). If REC exceeds 127, `nodeC` will go into *passive error mode*.

If you use the CANopen application layer, you can implement a combination of EMCY, PDO and HEARTBEAT protocols to ensure that `nodeC` enters a defined safe state if the CAN bus is disturbed.